# how to check non existent field added later using entityfieldquery?

Tags: 7, database, entities

I added a required field in a Job type node later. So existing nodes don't have that particular field value. 
I want to include all such field values. But how can I do it?

Here is query sample:

```
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', array('central_government_vacancy','psu_vacancy','state_government_vacancy'))
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    -> fieldCondition('field__expired_processed', 'value', 'NULL', '=')  //I'm looking for this field
    ->fieldCondition('field_last_date_of_application', 'value', $date, '<=');
```

In the above code I want to find nodes having uninitialized field values : field_expired_processed.

!=, or using NULL to compare does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you look on the [fieldCondition](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3afieldCondition/7) documentation page you will see the following warning:

> Note that entities with empty field values will be excluded from the EntityFieldQuery results when using this method.

Checking whether a field exists or not has been added to entityFieldQuery in Drupal 8, but unfortunately [won't be backported to Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/1157006).

This means you must use standard [SelectQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/class/SelectQuery/7) in order to achieve this. You must join the table which contains your data, and check whether the fiels IS NULL. It would be something like:

```
$q = db_select('node', 'n');
$q->condition('n.type', 'central_government_vacancy', '=')
->addJoin('LEFT', 'field_data_field_expired_processed', 'f')
->isNull('f.value');
$r = $q->execute();
```

Comment: It is possible with an `EntityFieldQuery` but you need to implement `hook_query_TAG_alter()` to do so

Comment: For Drupal 7 as workaround, see https://drupal.org/node/1157006#comment-7634027